# Magento 2 Join two table and dispaly value in grid

Tags: magento2, grid, join

```
public function addCustomerData($filter = null)
    {
        $customersSelect = $this->customerResource->getConnection()->select();
        $customersSelect->from(
            ['customer' => $this->customerResource->getTable('customer_entity')],
            'entity_id'
        );
        if (isset($filter['customer_name'])) {
            $customerName = $this->customerResource->getConnection()
                ->getConcatSql(['customer.firstname', 'customer.lastname'], ' ');
            $customersSelect->where($customerName . ' LIKE ?', '%' . $filter['customer_name'] . '%');
        }
        if (isset($filter['email'])) {
            $customersSelect->where('customer.email LIKE ?', '%' . $filter['email'] . '%');
        }
        $filteredCustomers = $this->customerResource->getConnection()->fetchCol($customersSelect);
        $this->getSelect()->where('main_table.customer_id IN (?)', $filteredCustomers);
        return $this;
    }
```

here i am getting all default value i want to get customer attribute in **`customer_entity_varchar`** table and display it in grid how to do this